# Why do some badges appear white in color and others are dark?

Tags: support, badges, design

I know why questions, answers and some other aspects of the site are color-coded and what they mean but I can't find why badges are color-coded. I'll include a snapshot to show what I mean.

[image: Snapshot of badge colors]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Tag badges](https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags) appear in white. When you earn enough upvotes and answers in a given tag you earn one of those badges (100 up and 20 answers, for bronze, 400 up and 80 answers for silver, 1000 up and 200 answers for gold). [General badges](https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=general) appear in black.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer :)

Comment: @tmwoods glad to help!

Comment: You earned rightfully your [first Nice Answer badge](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/23/nice-answer?userid=192622)! :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Awesome just noticed !!