# Why do some links to questions expand to reveal the title, and others do not?

Tags: discussion, bug, hyperlinks

First of all apologies:

- Sorry for picking on this particular "badges" question, as an example, it was chosen at *random*.
- Sorry for the confused nature of this post - it is a bit difficult to illustrate the issue, and I have tried the best I can, using code formatting and screen shots.

---

### The issue

Consider the rendering of this URL:

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171136/why-do-some-badges-appear-white-in-color-and-others-are-dark
```

which, in the actual question text that the reader sees, appears like this:

[Why do some badges appear white in color and others are dark?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171136/why-do-some-badges-appear-white-in-color-and-others-are-dark)

or in screenshot form:

> [image: Screenshot of resolved URL]

Why is it that some links to questions resolve themselves, to show the actual text of the question, rather than the URL, as the link above has, and others do not? When they do not, it is then necessary to add the link, either using the link button in the editor, like so:

```
[Why do some badges appear white in color and others are dark?][1]

  [1]: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171136/why-do-some-badges-appear-white-in-color-and-others-are-dark
```

or using the "inline" method, like so:

```
[Why do some badges appear white in color and others are dark?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171136/why-do-some-badges-appear-white-in-color-and-others-are-dark)
```

---

### A visual experiment

A simple test, that I have just performed, is with the link

```
https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/11893/how-does-coordinator-xbee-receive-data-from-router/
```

Here on SE Meta, it resolves correctly:

[How does coordinator XBee receive data from router?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/11893/how-does-coordinator-xbee-receive-data-from-router/)

or in image (screenshot) form:

> [image: Screenshot of resolved URL on Meta]

However, if I do the same on SE Robotics, which is, currently, in *beta*, I get the URL, not the resolved text:

> [image: Screenshot of non resolved URL on Robotics]

I have noticed this a lot, sometimes it resolves itself, and other times not. I work on SE beta sites a lot - probably 70% of my time is on beta sites, 30% on fully fledged SE sites. Now, after doing this test, as the link itself is to a beta site (Arduino is currently in beta), it is not the link *to* the site which is to blame. I am starting to think that it is beta sites *themselves* that can not resolve the links, that is to say, if a link is posted on a beta site, then it will not resolve itself.

---

### Footnote

Please note that I am **not** referring to modified links, for example, links that additionally point to specific answers or comments within the original post, as these will, understandably, not auto-resolve:

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171136/why-do-some-badges-appear-white-in-color-and-others-are-dark#answer-171137
```

[Why do some badges appear white in color and others are dark?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171136/why-do-some-badges-appear-white-in-color-and-others-are-dark#answer-171137)

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171136/why-do-some-badges-appear-white-in-color-and-others-are-dark#comment-506438
```

[Why do some badges appear white in color and others are dark?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171136/why-do-some-badges-appear-white-in-color-and-others-are-dark#comment-506438)

Nor am I referring to these types of question URLs:

```
https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8614/are-electronic-cigarettes-a-healthier-alternative-to-regular-cigarettes/15492#15492
```

which do not resolve correctly, either:

[Are electronic cigarettes a healthier alternative to regular cigarettes?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8614/are-electronic-cigarettes-a-healthier-alternative-to-regular-cigarettes/15492#15492)

To be honest I don't understand why they exist in this format, when clicking on the actual question title goes to this:

```
https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8614/are-electronic-cigarettes-a-healthier-alternative-to-regular-cigarettes
```

but that is a separate issue, that I don't wish to address here.

---

### Addendum

Whoops! Obviously, the examples in my footnote do render themselves correct, sometimes.... So,

```
https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8614/are-electronic-cigarettes-a-healthier-alternative-to-regular-cigarettes/15492#15492
```

*does* resolve itself, on SE Meta. However, why then, on SE Workplace, which is *not* a beta, in one of the answers to [What should my company's policy be about "vaping"?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/62459/what-should-my-companys-policy-be-about-vaping#answer-62464) does the URL not resolve itself? See screenshot:

> [image: Unrendered URL on SE Workplace]

Comment: @TimStone - [This answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108134/what-limitations-does-converting-question-links-to-links-with-titles-have#answer-108147) to that question does indeed _seem_ to address my issue. Also, point 3e in [balpha's post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108134/what-limitations-does-converting-question-links-to-links-with-titles-have#answer-108475) "Anything else does not work", seems to (unfortunately) answer my question. However, this was about 5 years ago. Has the code not changed since then? Are there any plans to address this issue?